# Progressive disclosure login and security

Tags: login, security, lean-ux, progressive-disclosure

More and more web sites are using the UX pattern "progressive disclosure" for login purposes. I understand that this is for better user experience and cleaner user interfaces.

Since I use my browser (Firefox, IE) to save passwords for many web-logins, I'd like to know if "progressive disclosure" improves or declines security of the login process.

- Are there two seperate entries stored in the browser (login name and password) or does the browser still understand that this is a single login with a login name and a password?
- Do browsers have special features to handle progressive disclosure during login?
- As a developer: Do I have to cheat the browser to tell this is one login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming progressive login is separate in two distinct pages**.

> Are there two seperate entries stored in the browser (login name and password) or does the browser still understand that this is a single login with a login name and a password?

Browsers *may* become smarter and detect this kind of login page(s) but if they don't then there will be two entries in your auto-complete data: one to fill the username field and another to fill the password field.

> Do browsers have special features to handle progressive disclosure during login?

They don't. It means that they can't nicely handle multiple accounts.

> As a developer: Do I have to cheat the browser to tell this is one login form?

Yes, do not use distinct pages. If you split login in two pages then you will probably break **password managers** and it is a major inconvenience you should avoid at all costs.

**Login is still one page**

> Are there two seperate entries stored in the browser (login name and password) or does the browser still understand that this is a single login with a login name and a password?

No, they're handled as usual.

> Do browsers have special features to handle progressive disclosure during login?

No, they do not need to because everything works as before.

> As a developer: Do I have to cheat the browser to tell this is one login form?

You do not have to *cheat* the browser. Take a look on how it's currently implemented for example by Google. **Username and password are still there together**, on the same `<form>`. When you click on *Next* the `<div>` that contains `<input type=text>` and relevant text is hidden and password becomes visible.

Do you have to do anything else? Nothing more than usual, properly fill `aria-`, `autocomplete` and `spellcheck` attributes and modern browsers will grant a good user experience.